# Performance of combining multiple class selectors

Tags: css, browser, css-selectors, frontend, cssom

I'm a front-end developer and I've been reading about the performance of CSS selectors and I wanted to ask you about a practice I use a lot in my projects to reuse styles `"see attachment 1"` and I wanted to know:

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of combining multiple class selectors `"see attachment 2"` to style an HTML element?
2. Does combining multiple class selectors affect the performance of a web page?
3. How do browsers interpret this combination? Does it take more time or effort to recognize this pattern; remembering that browsers read selectors from right to left?

It should be noted that `"attachment 1"` is how I would have my CSS style sheet, however `.btn.style1` and `.btn.style2` do not have any properties declared as they are separate `"see attachment 3"`.

```
/* Attachment 1 (Omit excessive use of </ div>.) */
<div class="mainHeader">
    <div class="btn style1">Lorem ipsum A</div>
    <div class="btn style2">Lorem ipsum B</div>
</div>
```

```
/* Attachment 2 */
.mainHeader {
    [property]: [value];
}

.btn.style1 {
    [property]: [value];
}

.btn.style2 {
    [property]: [value];
}
```

Note: In my CSS style sheet I would not declare the following selectors:

```
/* Attachment 3 */
.btn {
    [No properties]
}

.style1 {
    [No properties]
}

.style2 {
    [No properties]
}
```

Comment: 2) The simple answer is no. The complex answer is also no. 3) RTL is compoundselector-combinator-compoundselector, not simpleselector-simpleselector within each compound selector. Naturally it'd take more time as more classes are added, but again, see #2. Doubt that it takes more effort.

Comment: Thanks friend, I'll keep that in mind